# Meteor 1.2 and MongoDB scalability

Tags: mongodb, meteor, ddp

This is a general architectural question regarding Meteor and MongoDB's scalability.

- I understand that a Meteor client can query the database and receive ongoing and automatic updates to a query.
- Is there an open connection between the two? Is it implemented with DDP?
- On the Meteor server side, it there an open MongoDB *connection* for every client?

Comment: Your last question is extremely broad as it seems to ask for general advice on large-scale DB management, I suggest [edit]ing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Clients don't connect directly to the database. They connect to the server which connects to the database.

The client and server talk in DDP.

The server connects to the MongoDB database (not DDP).

I doubt anyone has ever had 1 million open connections with a meteor app yet. It's a scaling issue that like any other will be a challenge and will require many engineers and resources. The question as to how it should or would work with 1 million users can't be answered in a StackOverflow answer. Getting 10,000 servers might be a start...

Comment: Thanks, Eliezer. I think you answered my question, namely that the Meteor client talks to the Meteor server with DDP. Therefore, there will likely only be as many open MongoDB connections as there are Meteor servers. (Can I assume that it can leave open the connection and doesn't open an close a connection on every operation?)